# My Joomla site was working well but suddenly i got" SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM Error"

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

HI I'm new to Joomla development.And I have hosted the website. It was warking well for last 2 months and suddenly i got this Error.

If difficulties persist, please contact the System Administrator of this site and report the error below.

```
0 SQL=SELECT b.rules FROM z4cyb_assets AS a LEFT JOIN z4cyb_assets AS b ON b.lft <= a.lft AND b.rgt >= a.rgt WHERE (a.name = 'com_content') GROUP BY b.id, b.rules, b.lft ORDER BY b.lft
```

And when I try to login to the Back-End l Im geting this error:

An error has occurred.

```
0 SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `z4cyb_users`
```

Comment: Did you install anything new or update your version?  Is the error showing as a Joomla error page or message?

Comment: No i didnt install or update. error showing as a Joomla error page , and I cant goto the back-end too

Comment: Can you manually edit the configuration.php to turn on debugging and also turn your error reporting to development?   I'd also check database corruption, many hosts have a one click way to repair a database on their control panel, you could try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this.

There was an issue with the database connectivity and I have resolved it.

go to your Cpanel and check whether you can access the PHPMyadmin. Most probably it might not work. If that the case we can ask for the server support. 
After that you can go to the front end and see.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to enter /administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=database and click on left side fix button.